# Slow convergence when the error is small when solving a convex optimization problem

Tags: optimization, training-error

I implemented an algorithm to solve trace-norm regularized least square problem. I noticed something that when the error becomes small, the convergence becomes very slow. I "manually" fixed this phenomenon by running the algorithm in the debug mode and pause the execution and change the step size either, increasing it or decreasing it.  I am sure that it is a known phenomenon but not sure what it is called or what improvements I can do to fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: It could be a lot of things, have you checked it's not cycling? Do you have a tolerance level?

Comment: @user2974951 it is not cycling since it converged after 12 hours. This phenomenon persists regardless what the tolerance level is.